# can i pass two data to FlatList in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i want to pass two data (which is notification, replynotification these data are array) to FlatList in
NotifiCard component

is it possible?? this is my code

```
      const Notification = () => {
      const {notification, replynotification} = useSelector((state) => state.post);
      const dispatch  = useDispatch();

      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
          type:CHECKNOTIFICATION_REQUEST,
        })
      },[]);
        return (
        <FlatList
        data={notification}
        keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <NotifiCard
          item={item}
          />
        )}
        />
        );
    };

    export default Notification;
```

then how can i fix my code??

Comment: is the reply notification related to the notifications? why not have two different lists

Comment: @UdenduAbasili yes it related but it has to  distinguish both data how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I have correctly understood the question.
If you have two different array, notification and replynotification and you want to give both as a single array to a FlatList, you should you the spread operator(...), in that way you can spread all the data in a unique array.

```
const array = [
  ...notification,
  ...replynotification
]
```

In this way you will have one array with all the data you need.
Pay attention that if notification and replynotification have different structure, you will have an array with items that have different structures.

```
<FlatList
 data={array}
 keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
 renderItem={({item}) => (
  <NotifiCard
   item={item}
  />
 )}
/>
```

Comment: thank you if i use your code i can get data in Notificard.. but The notification data and replynotification data are not distinguished, and are combined. how can i get distinguished data?

Comment: Can you show me please the data structures ?
Anyway you could use array of object, so you can give your item a "kind" or "type" property to distinguish them.